# How to get 2 month facebook page token when I have 2 month facebook user token?

Tags: php, facebook

How to get 2 month facebook page token when I have 2 month facebook user token ?
That's just it.
I haven't managed to do it.
IS there a way to do it using just graph explorer ?
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can [get these access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) by querying `/me/accounts`. You must have the `manage_pages` permission in order to receive the access tokens.

Comment: I fixed it.Thankx Michael.It was a bit more complicated than you said so I will not mark it as the answer,sorry.

Comment: Fine, then I won't help you in future.

Comment: Don't know why you're upset